# Error: Cannot find module 'has-flag' when trying npx react-native@latest init

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When trying `npx react-native@latest init AppTest` i encountered this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'has-flag'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\supports-color\index.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-doctor\build\tools\healthchecks\androidHomeEnvVariable.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-doctor\build\tools\healthchecks\index.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-doctor\build\commands\doctor.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-doctor\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wiktor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\dea611a43221eddd\node_modules\supports-color\index.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

First thing I have done was to install the missing package with `npm install -g has-flag`

Result:

```
npm install -g has-flag

changed 1 package in 667ms

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

then trying the `npx react-native@latest init AppTest`, however I get the same error

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by running: `npm i react-native@latest -g` and then `npx react-native init myProject`.